# Photo effects in Gimp: How to improve color, depth of field, etc

Tags: gimp, pixelation, blur, focus

G' day dear Graphic-design-experts,

I am new to Stackexchange's Graphic Design and I have no clue if this is the right place to ask, so bear with me and steer me in the correct direction if i am  wrong in asking thanks.  I am new with Gimp and I would like to know if I can add an effect to my image.

I currently have this image:

[image]

I would like to make this image look like the below image in Gimp but I am new and I do not know how.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is many ways to accomplish that dept of field effect you are looking for, so I'll just link you to some of the tutorials I found:

http://www.ephotozine.com/article/creating-shallow-depth-of-field-using-gimp-9722

http://tutorialgeek.blogspot.com.ar/2011/02/fake-depth-of-field-in-gimp-dof.html

http://gimpguru.org/tutorials/simulateddof/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Nn2q1U1yGQ

As for making it look better, you probably want to do some [color grading](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ktxsz29JoKw) to accomplish a more [pleasant color combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory). I've found that choosing the right colors is key to making things look good. Here is a tool which I've found very usefull whenever deciding what colors I'd be using: https://kuler.adobe.com/.

Comment: hi there - mille grazie. Very helpful! THX alot

Comment: no problem mate, glad I can help :)